# Image Loads and then disappears

Tags: browser, google-chrome

I'm having this weird problem one of my pages. The page is XHTML valid, loads perfectly fine on Safari, Firefox but on Chrome the images load fine and then disappear instantly leaving that small icon that appears when the image is not found. I tried disabling all the javascript on the page, but still no luck. I can post a video of the behaviour, if that helps.

Many [others have experienced this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4f4114448b03b409&hl=en) in Chrome, but is there any workaround or solution for this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fonts need to be hosted on the same domain. Fonts hosted on sub1domain.domain.com and website loading from subdomain2.domain.com won't work.

Comment: Hi, How is this related if it's an accepted answer? Please explain a bit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ad blocker or a similar plugin is getting in your way?

Comment: Nope, its a fresh xp install. Chome with no plugins.

Comment: Can you try to load the images in a converter and save them again? Just to make sure Chrome doesn't stumble over broken files are something like that. Also, do you have the latest version of Chrome?